# Random Background when click button android

Tags: android

I just want to click to button and to change the Background image. here is my different codes

**array.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="image">
    <item>@drawable/photo</item>
    <item>@drawable/photo1</item>
    <item>@drawable/photo2</item>
    <item>@drawable/photo3</item>
    <item>@drawable/photo4</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_above="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/photo"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my **activity** code:

```
final LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Resources res = getResources();
    final TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.image);
    final Random random = new Random();

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) {

           int randomInt = random.nextInt(myImages.length());
           background.setBackgroundResource(myImages.getResourceId(randomInt,-1));
           int drawableID = myImages.getResourceId(randomInt,-1);
            background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);

        }

    });
```

it doesn't work , can you help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In xml, you are using RelativeLayout, but in activity code, you are LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting wrong layout in your code. You have taken the `RelativeLayout` in your xml file where as you are casting it into `LinearLayout` in your java file.

In your java file change the `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.

```
final LinearLayout background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
```

write this:

```
 final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the case is not the LinearLayout do this:

Change the definition of your array to

```
final String[] myImages = res.getStringArray(R.array.image);
```

And then, replace your onClick method for this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

       int randomInt = random.nextInt(myImages.length);
       int drawableID = myImages.getResources().getIdentifier(myImages[randomInt], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
       background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);

   }
```